# Error en el modulo pysimplegui

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, cmd

Estoy intentando ejecutar un simple programa importando el modulo **PySimpleGUI** pero al ejecutarlo me aparece el siguiente error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySimpleGUI'
```

He comprobado que versión del modulo tengo instalada y es la **4.33**. También lo he vuelto a instalar por si a caso pero el error persiste. ¿Alguna solución? ¡Gracias!

Comment: Podrías poner el código de cómo lo estás importando y usando? También verificá que estás corriendo el programa dentro del entorno donde tenes instalado el módulo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisa en la instalación de Python, que lo has instalado marcando todas las casillas, como la de instalar para todos los usuarios.

Luego, desde la línea de comandos, dirígete a la carpeta donde tienes instalado Python y ejecuta lo siguiente:

```
pip install PySimpleGUI
```

Lee atentamente el mensaje que te aparece ya que te indicará que ejecutes una comanda para actualizar el paquete.

Puedes encontrar mas información aquí : https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installing-pysimplegui